# Unable to extract the correct columns from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am creating a script to edit DNA sequence alignments by tracking errors from a test dataset. My goal is to keep a track of columns that contain stop codons below and over a certain threshold. For example, if a column (contains 3 bases or a codon) contains either "TAA", "TGA", or "TAG" and if over 40% of the samples contain one of those stop codons in the column, I want to keep a record of it in a separate excel file (which I can create) as those columns will be deleted. If less than 40% of the samples contain a stop codon in a column, I track that separately as those would need to be edited.

My dataframe looks something like this (I added "/" here just to show the codons here more easily):

```
    1    2  3    4 ... 1000
S1 TAA/TAA/TGA/CCC/.../TGA
S2 ATG/-AT/TAG/---/.../TGA
S3 ATG/TAA/-CC/--T/.../TAA
S4 ATG/TAA/GTA/CCC/.../TAA
S5 ATG/-AT/---/---/.../TAG
S6 ATG/TAA/-CC/--T/.../TAG
S7 ATG/TAA/GTA/CCC/.../CCC
S8 ATG/-AT/---/---/.../CCC
S9 ATG/TAA/-CC/--T/.../CCC
S10 ATG/TAA/-CC/--T/.../CCC
```

I can easily extract gapped columns (containing "---"), and I was able to track columns with stop codons over 40% but I am unable to track columns that contain less than 40%, and this is because it is looping through each of the 3 codons separately. For example if I have 10 samples, if less than 4 samples at column 1 contain "TAA" or "TGA" or "TAG" (in any combo), I would keep that record, and change the stop codons into "---" in the final edited dataframe. But when each of the stop codons show up less than 4 times each, my script is treating them individually and showing me columns with over 40% stops in it because I cannot figure out how to make it sum across all three codons and treat it as a total.

```
df # (loaded earlier from a large script)
df_track = pd.DataFrame() # make new df to track less than 40% stop codons in columns
codon = ["TAA","TGA","TAG"]
def track_lessthan40(df, codon, 0.4):
    num_rows = len(df)
    change = [col for col in df.columns \
        if sum(df[col] == codon[0]) > 0 or sum(df[col] == codon[1]) > 0 \
        or sum(df[col] == codon[2]) > 0 \
        and sum(df[col] == codon[0]) \
        and sum(df[col] == codon[1]) \
        and sum(df[col] == codon[2]) < round(num_rows*0.4, 2)]

df_change = df[change]
print(df_change)
```

What I expect:

```
df_change

    1  3
S1 TAA/TGA
S2 ATG/TAG
S3 ATG/-CC
S4 ATG/GTA
S5 ATG/---
S6 ATG/-CC
S7 ATG/GTA
S8 ATG/---
S9 ATG/-CC
S10 ATG/-CC
```

What I get.

```
    1  3  ... 1000
S1 TAA/TGA/.../TGA
S2 ATG/TAG/.../TGA
S3 ATG/-CC/.../TAA
S4 ATG/GTA/.../TAA
S5 ATG/---/.../TAG
S6 ATG/-CC/.../TAG
S7 ATG/GTA/.../CCC
S8 ATG/---/.../CCC
S9 ATG/-CC/.../CCC
S10 ATG/-CC/.../CCC
```

The last column shows up but it shouldn't. It should only be tracked in my other script when I want columns where stop codons appear in over 40% of the samples.
Any ideas on how to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that there may be a difference between the makeup of your sample code and the df you are using. Jon's slightly adjusted example and my script work for your sample (see image).

[image]

```
# my clunky example
import pandas as pd
csv = '/Users/<USER>/PycharmProjects/stackoverflow/gattaka.text'

df = pd.read_table(csv, sep='/')

df_track = pd.DataFrame()  # make new df to track less than 40% stop codons in columns
codon = ["TAA", "TGA", "TAG"]

for column in df.columns:
    col_length = len(df[column])
    col_list = df[column].tolist()

    sum_stopper = 0
    for gene in col_list:
        if gene in codon:
            sum_stopper += 1

    if sum_stopper == 0:
        break

    elif sum_stopper <= (0.4 * col_length):
        col_series = pd.Series(col_list, name=column)
        df_track[column] = col_series

print(df_track)
print('------')

# Jon's adjusted, pretty, concise and pythonic example
df_track = df.loc[:, (df.isin(codon).sum()/len(df) <= 0.4) & (df.isin(codon).sum() > 0)]
```

Comment: It's doing the opposite, it's giving me a table without those columns but I have to keep a record of those columns separately (in df_change), and then later I edit the stops into gaps in a new dataframe so I don't lose that entire column. The only time I remove the whole column is if stop codons occur in over 40% of the samples. The script also changed all my sample names into indices lol.

Comment: I am a little confused. I thought you required the data in the format shown in your answer as "what I expect:". I made some changes to the code. 
1. Columns that do not contain a stopper are ignored
2. Now only columns with more than 40% of stoppers are returned
3. Series are attached to the df - I hope that solves the "indices" conversion problem

Comment: Sorry, I have two sets of tables. In this question I opened, I want to get all the columns where stop codons appear in less than 40% of the samples (so they are present but not over 40%, and if it was over 40% I have a separate code to keep that in a separate file). Reason being, if they are present but less than 40%, I edit those stops into gaps. If they appear in over 40% of the samples, I delete that whole column. So what I had shown was what I expect to obtain when it is less than 40%. If over 40% I expect only that last column to appear.

Comment: I tried your code again but it's not working, just getting empty dataframes back. It works a bit with my script I just need a way for it to count all 3 stop codons in a column as the total of all being present in less than 40% of the samples.

Comment: In this version I added the text file that Jon and I used. There is nothing else I can do, good luck with that.

Comment: The list comprehension by Jon worked, but I have no idea now how to convert those positions into gaps. Will try to figure it out otherwise a second question might get posted :) I tried your code as well but it just kept returning an empty dataframe for me, I don't know why :S

Answer (score 2):

IIUC
`df.isin(codon).sum()/len(df) <= 0.4`
outputs

```
#    1       True
#  2        False
# 3          True
#   4        True
# 1000      False
```

and you can select the columns like so:

```
df.loc[:, df.isin(codon).sum()/len(df) <= 0.4]
```

using [`pd.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) to check if any one of the stop codons is in the columns, summing to count the number of times it is true and dividing by the length of the dataframe to get it as a percentage.

Comment: I tried that out, but it is returning the entire df for me not a new one with only the columns that I need. Is this supposed to go after my loop? I just tried what you typed alone without my for loop.

Comment: Well the sample dataframe I'm testing on actually has the 1000 columns lol, and I am getting every single one of them back.

Comment: It's turning an entire dataframe for me...is it incorrect if I use that line of code in my function? I commented out all of my lines in the for loop and used yours...maybe I am writing it out incorrectly.

Comment: Lets take this to chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185950/room-for-jondiedoop-and-dnangel